# When to use MessageDigest.reset()

Tags: java, hash, owasp, message-digest

I've blindly followed OWASP's recommendation on hash generation in java ([see here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Hashing_Java#Hardening_against_the_attacker.27s_attack)), and I'm not sure I've done it correctly. Specifically, I'm unsure about the purpose and effect of `MessageDigest.reset()`, and therefore when and how to use it.

1. I'm "loading" my salt and payload by `update()`ing the digest several times with different values that altogether need to be signed. Should I `reset()` the digest beforehand? Or afterwards?
2. Why is the digest being `reset()` within the loop (see the example)?

Here's my code:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
md.update(salt);
md.update(payload1);  // part 1 of payload
md.update(payload2);  // part 2 of payload
md.update(serialNumber);  // part 3 of payload
md.reset();
byte[] sig = md.digest();
for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
  md.reset();
  sig = md.digest(sig);
}
```

What I'm observing is that the signature remains the same even when `serialNumber` is changing. If I leave out the 'reset()' calls, the sig does change...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to call MessageDigest.reset() before using it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546549/do-i-need-to-call-messagedigest-reset-before-using-it)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You only need to call `reset` if you have already used that instance of `MessageDigest`. `reset` is being called here to clear all previous settings.

`MessageDigest.getInstance` is a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) rather than a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) so has significant overhead attached.

From [MessageDigest.getInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#getInstance%28java.lang.String%29):

> A **new** MessageDigest object encapsulating the MessageDigestSpi implementation from the first Provider that supports the specified algorithm is returned.

So better to re-use and avoid the overhead of calling `MessageDigest.getInstance` again.

Comment: So the OWASP example and my code are wrong, yes? If I always get a new instance, I don't need `reset` at all?

Comment: I would go with reset & re-use :)

Comment: @Hank - You aren't always getting a new instance as `.getInstance` is outside of the loop. Using `.reset` is fine here.

Comment: Thanks, your responses and a dose of thinking-about-them(tm) has completely answered my question!

Answer (score 7):

The code looks off to me... maybe I'm mis-reading here, but the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#digest%28%29) say `digest()` implicitly resets the instance. Thus, you'd call `reset()` if you had 1) previously called `update()` and 2) needed to re-use the instance, but didn't need the results from the `update()` calls.

In your case, I also think you need to leave out the first call to `reset()`. Otherwise, you are throwing away any benefit from the salt and payloads. The call to `reset()` inside the loop is unnecessary, but shouldn't change the results of the calculation.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Totally agree, the original code *was* off wrt first `reset()` call. Thanks for the pointer regarding implicit reset!